# Подстроки, в которых нет заданной строки

Tags: регулярные-выражения, c#

Есть строка: stringA chars1 stringB stringA chars2 stringB

Нужно получить:   
1) stringA chars1 StringB 
2) StringA chars2 StringB

Если задаю шаблон:

```
string pattern = @"stringA[sw]+stringB";
```

То в результате выдает всю строку: stringA chars1 stringB stringA chars2 stringB
Как сделать шаблон, который берет все возможные строки, в которых нет, к примеру, строки stringA? Или есть какой-то иной подход для решения данной задачи?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Это называется жадность регулярного выражения - оно старается выбрать максимальную строку, подходящую под заданный шаблон. Ленивость - наоборот, оно будет искать наименьшую строку.

В C# квантификаторы различаются на жадные и ленивые.

Жадные, например: *, +; ленивые, соответственно: *?, +?.
Использование ленивого квантификатора как раз и приведёт к тому результату, который Вы желаете:

```
string pattern = @"stringA[\s\w]+?stringB";
```

Тут об этом написано подробнее: [Кванторы](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/3206d374(v=vs.90).aspx).